# 3 regular graph equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image: The problem]
So I am completely lost on this problem. I had the idea to induct on the vertices since I can relate the number of edges to the number of vertices and also the number of faces to the number of vertices with Euler's equation. I also can find the sum of all of the sides of a face in relation to vertices but I just don't see how to prove the equation on $V+2$ vertices. It's inducted by 2 due to the handshake lemma.

I have $e=1.5v$, $f=2+.5v$ (from $v-e+f=2$).
And the sum of the sides of faces is $3v$ because the number of edges is $1.5v$ but edges get counted twice by faces.

Comment: You don't need induction. You have all the parts you need, such as $6f=12+3v$, but just have to put it together in terms of the $c_m$. For example, what is "the sum of the sides of faces" expressed in terms of the $c_m$? What is $f$ expressed in terms of the $c_m$?

Comment: That's my problem, I have been starring at this all weekend and I haven't had the light bulb go off on how to relate my current Equations to the Cm equations

Comment: What do you mean by "$c_m$ equations"? What do you think $c_m$ means?

Comment: Cm is the number of cycles that exist with m edges surrounding it. I don't see how to relate what I have to the equation I need to prove. I am not sure if what I have found is even relevant to the problem as a whole.

Comment: Not quite: $c_3$ is the number of 3-sided *faces*, $c_4$ is the number of 4-sided *faces*, etc. So what is the total number of faces $f$ expressed in terms of the $c_m$?